# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to boot from USB on raspberry pi 4

Tags: server, 20.04, usb, raspberrypi

As per the instructions on [USB Boot for Rpi-4](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#4-optional-usb-boot) from the official website, I updated bootloader to allow USB boot.

Flashed my USB drive with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server and connected to Raspberry Pi 4, but fails to boot.

Weird enough, both Ubuntu Desktop & Server(21.04) worked out of box using USB boot.

What additional steps should I follow, to allow USB boot?